# DXA 2.1 website returns 500 Internal Server Error after install

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-2.1

My DXA 2.1 out of the box website gives me an 500 Internal Server Error for some pages, but not for all.

The homepage at http://localhost:8852/ is working fine. The news pages, like http://localhost:8852/articles/news/news2 are raising the error. So this is likely to be content related.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed!, It's the bug in DXA 2.1 found and raised SRQ to fix this, somehow **Left Navigation** of include page not used correct import package file, it was not localized to use the correct page template.

In order to fix this issue manually localize this **Left Navigation** page and then change to select the page template to **Include Page (Left)** and republish it will fix this issue.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! A similar fix is to change the Left Navigation page in the "110 DXA Site Type" publication. Localization of the page is not needed in that case.

Comment: yup. that could also fix

Comment: @Jan: Please accept this Answer.

Comment: We had a hard time reproducing and analyzing this issue. It turned out to be a Sites 9.0 CM database issue which only reproduces if you're unlucky. This will be hotfixed soon.